# How can I select only first picture from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, inner-join, where-clause

How can I select ALL data from the first table and only select FIRST ROW icon from the other table if their ID's are equal?

My query (`(SELECT icon from pages p2 ...)` is not working):

```
SELECT * 
FROM project p
INNER JOIN grouping g ON p.ID = g.ID
           (SELECT icon FROM pages p2 WHERE p2.ID=p.ID
            ORDER BY picture LIMIT 0, 1)
WHERE g.num ='" . $id . "'
ORDER BY g.sort ASC
```

`icon` in the query is the thumbnail I need, but the sorting itself is based on `picture` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT pp.icon
        FROM pages pp
        WHERE pp.ID = p.ID
        ORDER BY pp.picture
        LIMIT 0, 1
       ) as icon
FROM project p     
WHERE g.num = ?
ORDER BY g.sort ASC;
```

Note that you should be passing in the `g.num` as a parameter, not munging the query string.  So, I changed the logic to use a parameter placeholder.

Comment: Thankyou. After adding `INNER JOIN grouping g ON p.ID = g.ID` to your code, it works perfectly.